# Как создать динамический массив с количеством элементов, которое вводит пользователь?

Tags: массивы, pascal

> Пользователь вводит размерность массива и его элементы. Создать
>   динамический массив с количеством элементов, которое вводит пользователь. Если
>   в массиве максимальный элемент четный, то увеличьте количество элементов на 5,
>   и новые элементы заполните значениями первых пяти элементов массива.
>   Выведите массив на экран с соответствующими пояснениями. Упорядочьте
>   элементы нового массива по убыванию методом пузырька. Выведите массив на
>   экран с соответствующими пояснениями.

Застрял на увеличении массива

```
const 
  Sz = 100;
var 
  a: array [1..Sz] of integer;
  b: array of integer;
  N: integer;   
  max: integer;
  minind: integer;
begin
  readln(N);
  for var i:=1 to N do
    a[i] := Random(100);
  writeln('Элементы массива: ');
  for var i:=1 to N do
    write(a[i],' ');
  writeln;  

  max := integer.MinValue;
  for var i:=1 to N do
    if (a[i]>max) then 
    begin
      max := a[i];
    end;

  writeln(max);
    if (max mod 2 = 0) then
    writeln(1) else writeln(0);

end.
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте динамический массив и `SetLength`:

```
var
  a: array of integer;        // <<-- Объявление динамического массива
  ...
begin
  readln(N);
  SetLength(a, N);            // <<-- Установка размера динамического массива
  for var i := 0 to N - 1 do  // <<-- Обратите внимание, элементы идут от 0 до N-1
  begin
    a[i] := Random(100);
  end;
  ...
```

Comment: не работает 
    не может вызвать ф-ю SetLength

Comment: @Moscowdev " не может вызвать ф-ю" - что это значит? Прямо говорит: "не могу"?

Comment: Program1.pas(27) : Не могу вызвать SetLength для операнда данного типа

Comment: @Moscowdev Потому что Вы не исправили декларацию массива `а`.

Comment: а не могли бы вы мне написать эту часть кода целиком?  Если в массиве максимальный элемент четный, то увеличьте количество элементов на 5, и новые элементы заполните значениями первых пяти элементов массива. Выведите массив на экран с соответствующими пояснениями   я что то туплю

Comment: @Moscowdev нет, не мог бы

Answer (score 2):

Динамический массив отличается от фиксированного тем, что для него не указан размер.

```
var
  a: array of integer;       <-динамический массив
  b: array[0..5] of integer; <-фиксированный массив
begin
  setlength(a, 10);
  setlength(b, 10); <-тут будет ошибка, т.к.массив b - фиксированный длины(от 0 до 5)
...
```

Вот небольшие пояснения:

```
var
  ...
  a: array of integer;
begin
  //ждем количество элементов от пользователя
  readln(N);

  //устанавливаем длину массива
  setlength(a,N);

  //заполняем массив
  for i:=0 to N-1 do
    a[i] := Random(100);

  ...

  //Если в массиве максимальный элемент четный
  if (max mod 2 = 0) then begin
    //то увеличьте количество элементов на 5
    setlength(a,N+5);

    //и новые элементы
    //(новые элементы - это от N и до последнего)
    for i:=N to length(a)-1 do
      //заполните значениями первых пяти элементов массива
      a[i] := ...
  end;

  //Упорядочьте элементы нового массива по убыванию методом пузырька.
  //Выведите массив на экран с соответствующими пояснениями.
  ...

end.
```